# Pass a pipe to a command that expects a filename

Tags: bash, pipe, command

Say I have a command `foo` which takes a filename argument: `foo myfile.txt`. Annoyingly, `foo` doesn't read from standard input. Instead of an actual file, I'd like to pass it the result of another command (in reality, `pv`, which will cat the file and output a progress meter as a side effect).

Is there a way to make this happen? Nothing in my bag of tricks seems to do it.

(`foo` in this case is a PHP script which I believe processes the file sequentially).

I'm using Ubuntu and Bash

EDIT
Sorry for the slightly unclear problem description, but here's the answer that does what I want:

```
pv longfile.txt | foo /dev/stdin
```

Very obvious now that I see it.

Comment: Are you looking for a one-liner?

Comment: Are you sure foo does not accept an argument of "-" to make it read from stdin?

Comment: Sadly yes, in this case - it's a php script.

Comment: Yes, actually. .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do properly, you can do it with bash's command substitution feature:

```
foo <(somecommand | pv)
```

This does something similar to what the `mkfifo`-based answers suggest, except that bash handles the details for you (and it winds up passing something like /dev/fd/63 to the command, rather than a regular named pipe).  You might also be able to do it even more directly like this:

```
somecommand | pv | foo /dev/stdin
```

Comment: oh, nice one! This `pv inputfile.txt | foo /dev/stdin` is exactly what I was looking for, but didn't think of.

Comment: Woot!  /dev/stdin

Comment: `<(.)` worked for me. Is this syntax documented in the Bash manual? I understand `(.)` as command substitution is documented, but did not see its combination with `<` explained.

Comment: @flow2k It's called "process substitution" -- see [section 3.5.6 of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Comment: Got it. You're right - it mentions that it uses named pipes/`mkfifo`.

Comment: If you're using this in a script, note you'll need to start the script with `#!/bin/bash` rather than `#!/bin/sh` otherwise this feature will throw an error instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
ARRAY=(`pv whatever`); for FILE in $ARRAY; do foo $FILE; done
```

Answer (score 2):

This Unix SE question has a an answer that shows how to create a temporary named pipe:

[Shell Script mktemp, what's the best method to create temporary named pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29851/shell-script-mktemp-whats-the-best-method-to-create-temporary-named-pipe)

Based on the answers there, you could do something like the following:

```
tmppipe=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo -m 600 "$tmppipe"
pv examplefile > $tmppipe
```

You could then watch the pipe with:

```
foo $tmppipe
```

Then delete it when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using mkfifo.

```
mkfifo file_read_by_foo; pv ... > file_read_by_foo
```

In another shell, run foo file_read_by_foo

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` seems to work well for this:

```
echo longfile.txt | xargs pv
```

Comment: That does something different: running `pv` multiple times, each with one or more lines  drawn from `longfile.txt`. Not at all what I'm after here.